# How can I find text after some string over bash

Tags: bash

I have this bash script and works

```
DIRECTORY='1.20_TRUNK/mips-tuxbox-oe1.6'

# Download html page and save to tmp folder to ump.tmp file
wget -O 'ump.tmp' 'http://download.oscam.cc/index.php?&direction=0&order=mod&directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;'

ft='index.php?action=downloadfile&amp;filename=oscam-svn'
st='-webif-Distribution.tar.gz&amp;directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;'
```

File ump.tmp containts e.g. three links

```
<a href="index.php?action=downloadfile&amp;filename=oscam-svn10082-mips-tuxbox-webif-Distribution.tar.gz&amp;directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;"></a>

<a href="index.php?action=downloadfile&amp;filename=oscam-svn10081-mips-tuxbox-webif-Distribution.tar.gz&amp;directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;"></a>

<a href="index.php?action=downloadfile&amp;filename=oscam-svn10080-mips-tuxbox-webif-Distribution.tar.gz&amp;directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;"></a>
```

I need find solution for find only number 10082 in first "a" links of the page. But this number is amended. When you run the script e.g per month, it may be different

I do not have the "cat" command. I have receiver and not linux. Receiver have enigma system and "cat" isn´t implemented

I tested through comparison "sed", but it does not work.

```
sed -n "/filename=oscam-svn/,/-mips-tuxbox-webif/p" ump.tmp
```

Comment: You don't need cat: you can use `<` or a pipe to get the output straight from a file into `grep` or `sed` to match the lines. But how do you not have `cat`??

Comment: ... "I do not have the 'cat' command" - That is a very odd statement, that says volumes, and yet not enough, about your system. Also - what distinguishes `10082` from `10081`, that you want the former and not the latter?

Comment: @Rup: I have receiver and not linux. Receiver have enigma system and "cat" isn´t implemented.

Comment: If you just need the first line, see if you have `head`. Its use would be `head -n1 filename` or a simple `read -r line <filename; echo $line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proper XHTML parser :

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//a/@href[contains(., "downloadfile")]' ump.tmp 2>/dev/null |
    grep -oP "oscam-svn\K\d+"
```

But there's not this string in the given HTML file

Comment: I have "HTML parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: td and table"

Comment: Added `2>/dev/null`. The html is not well written, but errors are not fatals, so now it's hidden

Answer (score 1):

"Find" is kind of vague, but you can use `grep` to get the link with the number `10082` in it from the temp file.

```
$ grep "10082" ump.tmp
<a href="index.php?action=downloadfile&amp;filename=oscam-svn10082-mips-tuxbox-webif-Distribution.tar.gz&amp;directory=$DIRECTORY&amp;"></a>
```